# XML to JSON with namespaces

Tags: json, xml, xslt, namespaces

I am trying to convert XML with XML namespace to JSON data  using XSLT as shown below:

Basically if the XML element has a node of the form element xmnls= "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-modulename" .                              The JSON translation should be                                                                   "ietf-modulename:element" as in example below

XML:

```
<notification
    xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf">
    <event-time>2013-12-21T00:01:00Z</event-time>
    <event>
    <event-class>fault</event-class>
    <reporting-entity>
    <card>Ethernet0</card>
    </reporting-entity>
    <severity>major</severity>
    </event>
 </notification>

JSON Conversion:

{
"ietf-restconf:notification": {
"event-time": "2013-12-21T00:01:00Z",
"event": {
"event-class": "fault",
"reporting-entity": { "card": "Ethernet0" },
"severity": "major"
}
```

Using the below xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">{
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Object or Element Property-->
  <xsl:template match="*">
  "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
                                       </xsl:template>

                                       <!-- Array Element -->
                                       <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
                                       </xsl:template>

                                       <!-- Object Properties -->
                                       <xsl:template name="Properties">
                                       <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
                                       <xsl:choose>
                                       <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:otherwise>{
                                         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                                           <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                                       }</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
  </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the namespaces are removed in this .
 How can I edit the XSL file to convert  to "ietf-restconf:notification" in JSON?

Another example :

```
<interfaces
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
<interface>
<name>0/4</name>
<type
xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:ethernetCsmacd
</type>
<enabled>false</enabled>
<link-up-down-trap-enable>enabled</link-up-down-trap-enable>
<ipv4
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
<enabled>false</enabled>
</ipv4>
<ipv6
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
<enabled>false</enabled>
<mtu>1500</mtu>
<forwarding>false</forwarding>
<dup-addr-detect-transmits>1</dup-addr-detect-transmits>
<autoconf>
<create-global-addresses>false</create-global-addresses>
</autoconf>
</ipv6>
</interface>
</interfaces>
```

should map to

```
    {"ietf-interfaces:interfaces": {
  "interface": {
    "name": "0/4",
    "iana-if-type:type": "ianaift:ethernetCsmacd
",
    "enabled": "false",
    "link-up-down-trap-enable": "enabled",
    "ietf-ip:ipv4": {
      "enabled": "false"
    },
    "ietf-ip:ipv6": {
      "enabled": "false",
      "mtu": "1500",
      "forwarding": "false",
      "dup-addr-detect-transmits": "1",
      "autoconf": {
        "create-global-addresses": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why would `"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf"` result in `ietf-restconf:`? Or `"http://example.com/event/1.0"` in `example-mod:`? And why would the namespace be attached only to `notification` and `event`, when all elements are in a namespace?

Comment: Can I not customise the XSLT this way ? I need it for RESTCONf standard of JSON , wherin <element> namespace  urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf should me mapped to ietf-restconf:<elementname>. Please ignore example-mod , remove it

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but the logic that needs to applied here is not clear.

Comment: Basically if the XML element has a node of the form                       <element xmnls= "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-modulename" >.                         The JSON translation should be                                                                   "ietf-modulename:element"

Comment: You are telling me *what*, but not *why*. Which makes it difficult to suggest *how*.

Answer (score 1):

The difficult piece of your requirements is the prefix.

When you say (slightly improved for readability):

> Basically if the XML element has a node of the form element
>   `xmnls="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-modulename"`, the JSON
>   translation should be "ietf-modulename:element" as in example below

it seems like you're talking about elements that have the `xmlns=""` namespace declaration. This isn't an attribute that the XSLT processor sees in the XML. It's the namespace that is bound to the element (and it's descendants unless they have a different namespace specified).

So instead of a `notification` element, it's really a

```
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf}notification
```

element.

In your example, all of the descendant elements are in the same namespace too.

`event-time` as an example:

```
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf}event-time
```

Here's a good namespace reference for better explanation: http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

I think the only thing you can do is check the namespace uri on the root element and then check to see if the default namespace has changed.

Looking at your examples, it seems like you're wanting part of the uri after the last `:`. You can get this by using a recursive template call, but it would be much easier in XSLT 2.0.

Here's an example. I'm indenting for readability, but it's not necessary. Just remove the template named `indent` and the `indent` variables and their references. (This would also be much easier in XSLT 2.0.)

It's not comprehensive, but works with your example and should give you a starting point.

Example can also be seen here: http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3i (NEEDS TO BE UPDATED WHEN SERVICE IS AVAILABLE)

**XML Input**

```
<interfaces
    xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
    <interface attr="x">
        <name>0/4</name>
        <type
            xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:ethernetCsmacd
        </type>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <link-up-down-trap-enable>enabled</link-up-down-trap-enable>
        <ipv4
            xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </ipv4>
        <ipv6
            xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ip">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <mtu>1500</mtu>
            <forwarding>false</forwarding>
            <dup-addr-detect-transmits>1</dup-addr-detect-transmits>
            <autoconf>
                <create-global-addresses>false</create-global-addresses>
            </autoconf>
        </ipv6>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="1">
    <xsl:variable name="prefix">
      <xsl:call-template name="getPrefix">
        <xsl:with-param name="uri" select="namespace-uri()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('{&quot;',$prefix,local-name(),'&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:text>: {&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:variable name="indent">
      <xsl:call-template name="indent">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="prefix">
      <xsl:if test="namespace-uri()!=namespace-uri(..)">
        <xsl:call-template name="getPrefix">
          <xsl:with-param name="uri" select="namespace-uri()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent,'&quot;',$prefix,local-name(),'&quot;: ')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:variable name="indent">
      <xsl:call-template name="indent">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="prefix">
      <xsl:if test="namespace-uri()!=namespace-uri(..)">
        <xsl:call-template name="getPrefix">
          <xsl:with-param name="uri" select="namespace-uri()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent,'&quot;',$prefix,local-name(),'&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:text>: {&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($indent,'}')"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',normalize-space(),'&quot;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="indent">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:if test="$level >= 1">
      <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$level - 1 >= 1">
      <xsl:call-template name="indent">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getPrefix">
    <xsl:param name="uri"/>
    <xsl:if test="namespace-uri()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($uri,':')">
          <xsl:call-template name="getPrefix">
            <xsl:with-param name="uri" select="substring-after($uri,':')"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$uri"/>
          <xsl:if test="$uri">:</xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
{"ietf-interfaces:interfaces": {
  "interface": {
    "name": "0/4",
    "type": "ianaift:ethernetCsmacd",
    "enabled": "false",
    "link-up-down-trap-enable": "enabled",
    "ietf-ip:ipv4": {
      "enabled": "false"
    },
    "ietf-ip:ipv6": {
      "enabled": "false",
      "mtu": "1500",
      "forwarding": "false",
      "dup-addr-detect-transmits": "1",
      "autoconf": {
        "create-global-addresses": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

The only difference in this output and the output you requested is with the `type` element. Michael explains this best in his answer:

> Note that in your (new) example, the `type` element is in the same
>   namespace as its parent node. The namespace declaration
>   `xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type"` does not
>   affect it. In fact, it does not affect any node in the entire XML.

Comment: "*I think the only thing you can do is check the namespace uri on the root element and only add the prefix there.*" Well, you *could* test for `namespace-uri()!=namespace-uri(..)` to detect elements that declare a new default namespace. Not sure what's the point of this, though.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - That's a good point. Rinky (OP) - If this is something that would help, let me know and I can update my answer.

Comment: How can I add namespace uri as prefix on all elements having the namespace, by modifying this xslt. It checks it and adds only at rrot element

Comment: Please check the new example in question. Michael as I had mentioned RESTCONF JSON standards require this specific mapping

Comment: @Rinky "*How can I add namespace uri as prefix on all elements having the namespace,*" You need to understand the difference between *having* a namespace and *declaring* a namespace. And also the difference between declaring a namespace and declaring a *default* namespace (without a prefix), which is inherited by the descendants. --- P.S. If you have a specification of how this is supposed to work, point us to it.

Comment: @Rinky - I updated my question. I haven't looked at the spec. If you truly need `type` to have the prefix (see Michael's comment above about the differences in having/declaring a namespace) you may need to do some preprocessing of the XML outside of XSLT.

Comment: I still need to update the xsltransform.net example. That website is currently down.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Michael..As per the spec , it seems namespace can also be of the form  namespace "http://example.com/foodmod" . In this case , the elemnt should be of the form "foomod:top": .. Can I make your XSLT work for both type of namespace "http://example.com/foomod" and xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:foomod " the same way

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before you output the element's name:

```
<xsl:if test="namespace-uri()!=namespace-uri(..)">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(namespace-uri(), 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:'), ':')"/>
</xsl:if>
```

This is based partly on the following statement from the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netmod-yang-json-06#section-4) you linked to:

> A namespace-qualified member name MUST be used for all members of a
> top-level JSON object, and then also whenever the namespaces of the
> node and its parent node are different.

and partly on your statement that:

> my requirement is everything after "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:"
> should be extracted and added as prefix to any element having
> namespace

Note that in your (new) example, the `type` element **is** in the same namespace as its parent node. The namespace declaration `xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type"` does not affect it. In fact, it does not affect any node in the entire XML.

---

Unrelated to your question: I would suggest you use `xsl:text` to provide the JSON markup and indenting. This will make your stylesheet more readable and easier to modify.

Comment: I have shortened it in http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6k/20  But it is not extracting xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type" for the type element.

Comment: @Rinky "*it is not extracting xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type" for the type element.*" No, of course it isn't. I have explained why in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I would not like to hard code to "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:" it and extract the namespace for all types of namespaces on the spec. like http://example.com/foomod and xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:foomod ..how can i change my existing xsl http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6k/21 for the same .

Comment: @Rinky We need *rules*, not examples. I asked, in my very first comment on your question, what is the logic by which the namespace needs to be modified. You still haven't answered that.